# fail to use forked dependency from npmjs

Tags: npm, package.json, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps, agm

I need to add a feature to get a list of grouped markers by the marker clusterer of this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/markerclusterer

Currently - there is no such ability and it seems that the repo is not updated for a long time.

I have forked the github repo from here:

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps

Then I have made a commit of the required changes:

https://github.com/neverlose-lv/angular-google-maps/commit/eed277876549b58b41ee7d9515a47f07e5cb3115#diff-2cf0d0f0bfd8c7ff9b29a7feb0a963480b32b65116abe7a863115e63fb67c16fR78

And now - I am unable to use it.

Because, when I install the dependency via `npm instll neverlose-lv/angular-google-maps` command - the dependency is installed as the source code of the github repo, but to work - it should be the build files (`dist/` directory I guess. The result of `npm run build:prod`) command.

I am unable to publish the repo via `npm publish` command.
I get an error: `npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`

I have tried to make a build:
`npm install`
`npm run build:prod`

The build succeeded with some warnings.
Then I commited the build files to another repo:

https://github.com/neverlose-lv/markerclusterer-dist

And when I try to use it (`npm install neverlose-lv/markerclusterer-dist`) - I get dependency errors, which are listed in the `peerDependencies` directive.

So far I did myself...

I would like to know how can I correctly for and use this package ?

Answer (score 0):

The error `npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')` when doing `npm publish` might be caused by missing or empty `name` property in the `package.json`. Add value to `name` and try again.